# Interface builder doesn't stretch subviews of custom view

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I've created custom view (FAQItemView) with one inner UILabel, that is constrained to four sides of superview. Here is the source code of this view:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class FAQItemView: UIView {
    var questionLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(questionLabel)
        questionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        questionLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        questionLabel.textAlignment = .center
        questionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        questionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        questionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        questionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        questionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        questionLabel.text = "question"
        questionLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

I've added FAQItemView in Interface Builder and constrained its width to 200px. In such case inner label of FAQItemView should stretch to the size of FAQItemView. All is ok when i run app, but in Interface Builder label is positioned in the left side of container with its default (intrinsic) size.

The sample project is available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2923l8exqtg3ir/testapp1.zip?dl=0. Here FAQItemView has red background and the inner label has green background. In runtime the red color isn't visible because label has green background but in Interface Builder red color is also visible (to the right of label with green background)

Could somebody say what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

[UPD: Screenshot of view in interface builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKhxr.png)

Comment: Please add the image as a part of question. Cant access your drop box link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops...

Don't set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on your custom view *itself*.

So, just remove the first line in `setup()`:

```
func setup() {
    //translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work, thanks. But i'm a bit surprised why it works. Why shouldn't I set this property for view itself? Does Interface Builder internally use autoresizing masks? Is there some information about that?

Comment: To use AutoLayout for the UI component you create with code, you need to use translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false. If this is done from the IB then you don't need to touch that.

Comment: @Serega - as I understand it, views you *add as subviews* in IB automatically set that subview's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to false, but for the ***base view*** it remains true. Seems a bit confusing and maybe counter-intuitive...

Comment: @DonMag and IB sets translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false for my view anyway as this view has been added through IB. So it seems IB expects for any view to have translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true. Some sort of bug, I think.